# Historia de la palabra "lavanda" para referirse de forma común al "espliego"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, vocabulario, sustantivos, plantas

Según mis recuerdos, cuando era pequeña, para nombrar a la planta silvestre con flores azules en forma de espiga con un intenso olor muy perfumado, que se encuentra a veces caminando por la montaña, se hablaba de "espliego" y no de "lavanda". Ahora, en cambio, la palabra "lavanda" es en mi entorno muy habitual para designar a la [misma planta](https://dle.rae.es/lavanda?m=form). Me pregunto cuándo y por qué se introdujo el término "lavanda" para denominar a estas plantas.

De hecho, en *Rancés. Diccionario ilustrado de la lengua española*, de la editorial Sopena, publicado en 1974, aparece la voz "espliego", pero no "lavanda". Se trata de un diccionario escolar, de manera que el número de entradas es limitado. Pero el hecho de que "lavanda" no aparezca nos hace ver que no era un término tan común como lo es hoy en día.

Creo que la primera vez que oí hablar de "lavanda" para referirse a la planta silvestre
fue en una estancia en Francia cuando era adolescente, un día que me llevaron de excursión. Los adultos que nos acompañaban vivían en Montpellier. Esto me cuadra con la información que da el DLE sobre el origen francés (o italiano) del vocablo. Leyendo la entrada del DLE, pienso que el uso en castellano puede provenir de la perfumería. ¿Es así? ¿Se ha pasado de un uso específico (más o menos "técnico") en perfumería por influjo de productos franceses o italianos a un uso más generalizado que incluye el nombre común de las plantas silvestres o cultivadas?

Comment: Intresante, @Sisifo: Domínguez era un experto en francés.

Comment: Su uso viene desde mucho antes. En la hemeroteca de la BNE encuentro este texto de 1798: _En la calle de Bordadores [...] se ha abierto una tienda Almacen de todo género de Perfumeria, en la que contiene [...] todo género de aguas de olor, que acaban de llegar de Francia, como es lima, tomillo, bergamota, macuba, de clavel, almizcle, lavanda, agua del carmen, agua de cachirulo [...]._ Y en el CORDE hay algunos más antiguos, como este de 1765: _¿Tenéis agua de Lavanda?_ Puede que la voz francesa sonara mejor o simplemente se considerara de mayor prestigio.

Comment: Muy interesante, @Charlie: parece que se usaba en perfumería y no para llamar a la planta cuando te la encontrabas caminando por la montaña, cosa que cuadra con mis recuerdos.

Comment: No solo era usado en la perfumería, sino también en la medicina popular. En [_Secretos de la Agricultura del Prior_](https://www.google.cl/books/edition/Añadido_con_el_libro_quinto_y_un_vocabu/Au1eAAAAcAAJ?hl=es-419&gbpv=1&dq=lavanda&pg=RA2-PA237&printsec=frontcover), fechado nada menos que en 1703, hay una receta de "azeyte de espicanardi" en la que puedes reemplazar el espicanardo por lavanda. Lo recomiendan para "los dolores fríos del estómago".

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavandula) el nombre latino de la planta (o al menos de la familia a la que pertenecen las muchas plantas similares que hoy día conocemos como lavanda, entre ellas el espliego) es *Lavandula stoechas*.

El espliego es una de estas plantas *lavanduláceas* que, como digo, a menudo se denominan muchas de ellas bajo el nombre "lavanda", pero son distintas especies con sus propios nombres y cualidades.

También, el nombre original que se da en inglés al espliego es *Lavender*.

En general, atendiendo al uso que se hace de las palabras da la sensación de que "lavanda" es la traducción del original latino que hace referencia a la familia, pero que en el uso diario se ha trasladado a muchas de las plantas que engloba dicha familia.

También acorde a la wikipedia, la palabra "lavender" en inglés comienza a utilizarse en el siglo XIII, y se piensa que deriva de la francesa "lavandre" que, a su vez, deriva de la latina "lavare", y se ha utilizado de manera imprecisa para referirse a las plantas de la familia de las *lavanduláceas* en diversos países europeos con lenguas vernáculas derivadas del latín.

Es de suponer que en español estemos ante el mismo caso.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación. Todo esto ya lo había visto, pero no es lo que estoy preguntando. Ten en cuenta que el "original latino" es en realidad un cultismo introducido por los expertos en botánica.

Comment: He visto lo que has añadido, pero tampoco estoy preguntando por la etimología del inglés "lavender".

Comment: Además, el DLE ya deja claro que el término en español deriva del  francés *lavande* o el italiano *lavanda*. No es esa la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En el año 1875 don Zorobabel Rodríguez se quejaba en su [Diccionario de Chilenismos](https://www.google.cl/books/edition/Diccionario_de_chileniamos/9LANAAAAIAAJ?hl=es-419&gbpv=1&dq=agua%20de%20la%20banda&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover):

> **AGUA DE LA BANDA**
>
> Así han traducido en Chile el *eau de labande* que traen los rótulos de algunas ampolletas de esencias i perfumes, en lugar de *agua de alhucema*.
>
> <<Despidiendo un olor de agua de colonia, de la banda i de varios *bouquets* etc.>>
> (A. Blest Gana.- *Martín Rivas*.)

Asímismo, en el [Diccionario de Barbarismos y Provincialismos de Costa Rica](https://www.google.cl/books/edition/Diccionario_de_barbarismos_y_provinciali/vxRAAAAAYAAJ?hl=es-419&gbpv=1), publicado en 1891, se lee:

> **Agua de la banda.**
>
> Los barberos, perfumistas y demás personas *ejusdem farinae*, llaman
> *agua de la banda* al agua de *espliego* ó *alhucema*, porque ignoran que de este último modo se traduce el *eau de lavande* que se lee en
> el marbete de los botecillos de esencias francesas. El espliego ó
> alhucema se llama en francés *lavande*, en italiano *lavanda*, y en
> castellano antiguo *lavándula*.

Por lo tanto, respondiendo a tu pregunta, sí, el uso de la palabra "lavanda" se habría importado desde Francia en las etiquetas de los perfumes.

Estos ejemplos son latinoamericanos, pero podría intuirse una situación similar y anterior en Europa. Lo más antiguo que pude encontrar, también con la simpática falta de ortografía, es en el [Diario de Madrid del 13 de Mayo de 1811](https://www.google.cl/books/edition/Diario_de_Madrid/nYqJ3DnZ1jkC?hl=es-419&gbpv=1&dq=agua%20de%20la%20banda&pg=PA535&printsec=frontcover), donde una fábrica de aguardientes nos ofrece *Espíritu de xabon de la banda*, entre otros productos comerciales.

Comment: Creo que podrías incluir algún ejemplo de los que ha encontrado @Charlie.